# How to parse server password with subprocess.Popen in Django?

Tags: django, django-views

I have a simple form where user inputs remote host, username and password of their server. I process the form using upload_file view in my views.py. I want to run the following command with the input provided by the user:

```
rsync --list-only username@serveraddress
```

To run the following command user must type password and after successful authentication the file will be listed. I already take password input from the user however I don't know how to use it. After immediately running the above command password must be inputted in the terminal. How do I implement the same thing in Django? Here's my views.py:

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':    
        #session_name = request.POST.get['session']
        url = request.POST.get('hostname', False)
        username = request.POST.get('username', False)
        source = str(username) + "@" + str(url)
        command = subprocess.Popen(['rsync', '--list-only', source], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
    return render_to_response('thanks.html', {'res':result, 'res1':command}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        pass
    return render_to_response('form.html', {'form': 'form'},  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: What's the problem? Is there a problem with the output of `res1`? Don't know what your question is.

Comment: I am not able to access to server. It's obvious. They want me to enter the password. The password prompt is given in terminal where the server is running. Now I want to automatically fill the password input from the user_input. I have to manually type the password of the server in the terminal which is not possible or practical in live application.

Comment: What do you mean 'not able to access the server'? At what point do you discover this? Where is it breaking? What versions are you using? Seriously. http://whathaveyoutried.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the title of this question is a bit miseading, maybe it should be "How to *pass* server password...". Anyways, if I understand correctly, you can set the environment variable RSYNC_PASSWORD:

```
command = subprocess.Popen(['rsync', '--list-only', source],
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           env={'RSYNC_PASSWORD': my_password}).communicate()[0]
```

beware, environment variables may be visible to other system users

if that scares you you could use the rsync option `--password-file` (see rsync manual)

one more nit: by specifying `env` caller environment is not passed to rsync process anymore.

Comment: @mpaoline: Hey bro...Sorry to bother you but the above line of code didn't pass the password.

Comment: I already set the environment variable: echo $RSYNC_PASSWORD
/usr/bin/rsync

Comment: hmmmm, so if you do `print subprocess.check_output(['bash', '-c', 'echo $RSYNC_PASSWORD'])` you see the password printed?

Comment: Nope. Not printing the password.

Comment: that means that you are not setting the env var. in bash you do it with `export RSYNC_PASSWORD="mypass"` or just `RSYNC_PASSWORD="my_pass" python myscript.py`

Comment: from python you can also check with `import os; print os.environ.get('RSYNC_PASSWORD')`

Comment: do `export RSYNC_PASSWORD="my_pass"` and then `python -c "import os; print os.environ.get('RSYNC_PASSWORD')"`